# Objective-C Raw MD5-hash

Tags: objective-c, binary, char, md5

In Objective-C, I generate a simple MD5-hash of 'HelloKey', which returns `0FD16658AEE3C52060A39F4EDFB11437`. Unfortunately, I could not get a raw return, so I have to work with this string to get a raw MD5-hash (or do you know how I can get a raw result from the start?)

Anyway, in order to convert it to raw, I split it into chunks of 2 chars each, calculate the hex value, and append a char with that value to a string.

Here's the function:

```
- (NSString *)hex2bin:(NSString *)input{

    NSString *output = @"";

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i+=2){

        NSString *component = [input substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 2)];

        unsigned int outVal;
        NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:component];
        [scanner scanHexInt:&outVal];

        /* if(outVal > 127){
            outVal -= 256;
        } */

        // unsigned char appendage = (char)outVal;

        output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%c", output, outVal];

        NSLog(@"component: %@ = %d", component, outVal);

    }

    return output;

}
```

When I print each outval, I get:

```
0F = 15
D1 = 209
66 = 102
58 = 88
AE = 174
E3 = 227
C5 = 197
20 = 32
60 = 96
A3 = 163
9F = 159
4E = 78
DF = 223
B1 = 177
14 = 20
37 = 55
```

However, when I print the string that I get with a special function that tells me the integer values of each character (a function which is shown here):

```
- (NSString *)str2bin:(NSString *)input{

    NSString *output = @"";

    for (NSInteger charIdx=0; charIdx < input.length; charIdx++){


        char currentChar = [input characterAtIndex:charIdx];
        int charNum = [NSNumber numberWithChar:currentChar].intValue;

        output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d", output, charNum];

    }

    return output;

}
```

I get: `15 20 102 88 -58 30 72 32 96 -93 -4 78 2 -79 20 55`. You will notice that there are significant differences, like 209 -> 20, 174 -> -58, 227 -> 30. In some cases, the difference is 256, so no harm done. But in other cases, it's not, and I would really like to know what's going wrong. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, since you are trying to store binary data in NSString, which is UTF8 string.
You should use NSData (or C string) to store binary hash representation.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What's the best way to append binary to NSData objects?

Comment: As for me, i'll use setLength of NSMutableData and later set c-style byte array [data bytes] or something like that